# N objects among K persons

Tags: permutations, combinations

In how many ways can we distribute N objects among K people such that each person recieves AT LEAST ONE object ? Also the SUM MUST BE EQUAL TO N.

eg. 7 objects can be distributed among 5 people in 2 ways.

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
```

Other permutations of these are considered 'same'.

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 3) is same as (1, 1, 1, 3, 1).
```

Comment: You’re looking for the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $N$ into $K$ parts; there is no nice formula for this. You’ll lots of information and references [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is called a *partition* of $N$ into $K$ parts, see [this wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_partitions). There is no simple formula.

If you *had* cared exactly which person gets how many (so $(1,1,1,1,3)$ is different from $(1,1,1,3,1)$ and so on), we get a much simpler solution: first give each person one object. This can only be done in one way. Then the number of ways to distribute the remaining $N-K$ objects is a classical application of the technique known as [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), which gives an answer of $\binom{N-1}{N-K}$.